# A calculation with BF-theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, topological-field-theory

Consider the action of the abelian BF theory (a topological Quantum field theory)

$S = \int_M (B \wedge dA + j \wedge A) (1)$

$M$: 4-dimensional manifold

$A$: 1-form abelian gauge Connection

$j$: a 3-form current (it is a fixed field)

$B$: Another 2-form field

This action is invariant under abelian gauge transformations. I want to compute the Partition function $Z = \int d[A] \int d[B] e^{iS}$ and I know that I do a perturbative Expansion as follows:

$Z = \int d[A] \int d[B] e^{i\int_M B \wedge dA} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(i\int_M j \wedge A)^k = \int d[A] \prod_{x \in M}\delta (dA(x)) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(i\int_M j \wedge A)^k (2)$.

All constant factors can be singled out of the Partition function. The next step I do is the Hodge decomposition $A = d \phi + \Delta C + A_h$, where:

$\phi:$ 0-form field

$\Delta = *d*$ (exterior co-derivative)

$C:$ 2-form field

$A_h:$ 1-form field that is in the set of harmonic functions

The term $d \phi$ makes no contribution due to gauge invariance of the action (1)(i.e. it is simply an abelian gauge transformation). Substitution of the hodge decomposition into (2) yields:

$Z = \int d[C] \int d[A_h] \prod_{x \in M}\delta (d\Delta C(x)) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(i\int_M j \wedge (\Delta C+A_h))^k (3)$.

Equation (3) is an integral over fields $C$ and $A_h$, both must be harmonic ($C$ is also harmonic because of the factors $\delta(d \Delta C(x))$). In General, one has Solutions of linear harmonic differential equations:

$C(x) = \int_\Omega d^4y K_C(x-y) C_0(y), A_h = \int_\Omega d^4y K_A(x-y) A_{h0}(y) (4)$.

The fields $C_0,A_{h0}$ are boundary conditions that apply on topological regions like "holes" denoted by $\Omega$, while $K_C,K_A$ are corresponding integral kernels. Finally, integrals in (3) run only over these boundary conditions after substituting the solutions (4) into (3).

**My question:** Am I right so far? Or are there some mistakes? Which topological invariants I get after computing expectation values of products $A_\mu A_\nu \dots$, where probability density is $e^{i \int_M B \wedge dA}$?

Comment: $A_\mu$ is not gauge invariant, so correlation functions of gauge fields are not meaningful and do not compute topological invariants. The basic gauge-invariant operators are Wilson loops, and their correlation functions compute linking numbers of the loops. For some reviews of BF theories, see [Birmingham et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157391901175), [Kapustin-Seiberg](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0740v2), [Maldacena-Moore-Seiberg](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108152v2), and references therein.

Comment: Yes, I know that these products are not gauge invariant, but if the current $j$ does absorb the gauge transformations of  $A$ then correlation functions can be formed by computing products of $j \wedge A$

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by "absorbing gauge transformations".

Comment: The term $d\phi$ is an abelian gauge Transformation. The Partition function does not Change after performing this Transformation (this is what I meant with "absorbing gauge transformations").